# Syncing customer's changes from ftp to git

Tags: git, static, ftp, webserver, synchronization

We have a website, which is being developed for a customer, using git.

The files are uploaded to the web server.

The customer can then make changes to the site using ftp, changing the HTML files.

What's the best way to sync these changes to our git server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `rsync` (or copy) them into a repo clone, and run something like `git commit -am"auto sync from customer ftp"`?

Comment: Yes, we're probably going to do this. Thanks :-)